# Does a static lock object need to be final when using a synchronized(lock object) block?

Tags: java, synchronization, synchronized

Assume I have a

```
private static Object lock = new Object();
```

and somewhere in the same class

```
public void run() {
synchronized(lock) {
    //only 1 thread here, all others wait
  }
}
```

I always read that the lock object should be final, but not exactly why.
Assume I know for 100% that my code doesn't touch the lock object anywhere,
if one omits the final keyword, does this mean that the synchronization is **not 100% bulletproof**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the `final` in this context is only a good practice.

You can synchronize using any object, `final` or non final, `static` or non static.

Using together `final` and `static` will give you the security that nobody will synchronize the same code on a different lock. Without using the `final` you are not sure that somewhere in the code that variable is not reassigned.

Generally speaking using `final` for a variable that is never reassigned after inited it's a good programming practice. It improves readability because who reads your code knows that this variable will never been reassigned also without reading the full code.

Comment: Ok thanks, I had some unexpected behaviors and noticed that I'm missing the final at the lock. But I am sure that there's no other place which reassigns it, so I might have to look elsewhere

Comment: @ToniKanoni which kind of undesired behaviour do you have?

Comment: Basically the code inside the synchronized block was executed too many times, that never happened before. We're just rerunning the application to see if it happens again. It's just good to know that I need not worry about the forgotten "final"

Comment: “*But I am sure that there's no other place which reassigns it*” Do you see the issue? By declaring the variable `final`, you are not only sure, you *know* it.

Answer (score 3):

Without the final modifier you are relying on however the object was initialized to make it properly visible, and assuming that nothing changes its value. Since it is static then the initialization occurs when the class is loaded and there are visibility guarantees, so technically you can get away with leaving it non-final. (Although the code uses a synchronized block the lock being used has to be evaluated before the block is entered of course.)

If the lock object is changed for another one while it is in use, then two threads can be in the same section of protected code, and the whole locking scheme is compromised. Adding  the final keyword here would mean the compiler is helping you make sure this lock doesn’t change, and will result in a compile error if someone later tries to change it.

It’s generally a good thing to get as much help as you can from the compiler, and a compile will show you whether the field is changed or not, so it is a low risk change to make that makes sure a big problem can’t happen.

Comment: @Holger: yes I remember reading the spec on how the lock gets evaluated, that all makes sense, thanks.